# codeigniter dompdf page break issue during maximum table records

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, codeigniter-2, dompdf

For limited table records pdf looking good.

All table records are looking good in "echo $html", but after pdf creation page break is not working when table records are maximum. It creates first 4-5 pages empty during maximum records.

codeigniter dompdf page break issue during maximum table records:

My code snippet:

//controller code

```
function pdf_create($html, $filename='', $stream=TRUE) 
    {
        require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        $dompdf->load_html($html);
        $dompdf->render();
        if ($stream) {
            $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
        } else {
            return $dompdf->output();
        }
    }
```

//view file code

```
    ......
       ......  
        <tr>
                <td>
              <table width="100%" border="0" style="border:solid 1px #BFBFBF; page-break-inside: auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
       <tr bgcolor="#BFBFBF">
        <td><p style="font-size:14px; margin:0px;">Product Name</p></td>
        <td><p style="font-size:14px; margin:0px;">Product Quantity</p></td>
        <td><p style="font-size:14px; margin:0px;">Product Price</p></td>
        <td><p style="font-size:14px; margin:0px;">Total Price</p></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
$product_title = $product_details['product_titles'];
$prod_quantity = $product_details['product_qty'];
$price = $product_details['product_price'];
$total_price = $product_details['product_cal_price'];
$i = 1;
$j = 0;
$productwisetotal = 0;
foreach ($product_title as $value) { $productwisetotal += $value; ?>      
          <tr style="font-size:12px;" valign="top">
              <td style="border-right:solid 1px #BFBFBF"><?php echo $i.'. '.$value; ?></td>
              <td style="border-right:solid 1px #BFBFBF"><?php echo $prod_quantity[$j]; ?></td>
              <td style="border-right:solid 1px #BFBFBF"></td>
              <td style="border-right:solid 1px #BFBFBF"></td>
          </tr>
<?php    $i++;
         $j++;
       } ?>      
    </table>  

                </td>    
                </tr>
        .....
        .....
```

please give me idea how can i add page break in pdf when table contains maximum records??

Answer (score 2):

Add the `page-break-inside: auto` for the parent table like bellow

```
<table style="page-break-inside: auto">
<tr>
<td>

<table width="100%" border="0" style="border:solid 1px #BFBFBF;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
       <tr bgcolor="#BFBFBF">
-------
</table>
```

Comment: but my parent table is not in foreach.. nested tables are there.. can i apply it for <tr> ?? please suggest changes in my code?

Comment: page-break-inside: auto is the best way to add  page break.can you try it on tr or table

Answer (score 0):

```
        $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
        $html = $this->load->view('client_tid_pdf', $data,true);
        $mpdf->autoPageBreak = true;
        $mpdf->setAutoTopMargin='stretch';
        $mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch';
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).